# awk: getting a certain value

Tags: regex, awk, find

```
Identifiable: fasdf/=egbalid=/more.garble/XY=foo.bar.baz
```

I have a line that can be uniquely identified with `/Identifiable/`. What I'd like to have is the value of `XY` (in this case `foo.bar.baz`). How can I get that in awk?

Comment: Is `XY=` always at the end of the line? Show a broader sample input so the solutions can be more accurate.

Comment: @fedorqui  **we** are thinking about `[^=]*$`  :)

Comment: @fedorqui I think it happens 95% of the time. Which is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could use grep for this purpose.

```
grep -oP '^(?=.*\bIdentifiable\b).*\bXY=\K[\w.]+' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'Identifiable: fasdf/=egbalid=/more.garble/XY=foo.bar.baz' | grep -oP '^(?=.*\bIdentifiable\b).*\bXY=\K[\w.]+'
foo.bar.baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the XY value is always at the end of the line (it's always hard to guess when just 1 line of sample input is posted):

```
$ awk -F= '/Identifiable/{print $NF}' file
foo.bar.baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
echo "Identifiable: fasdf/=egbalid=/more.garble/XY=foo.bar.baz" | awk -F"XY=" '{print $2}'
foo.bar.baz
```

Comment: This would almost work, I have to use `awk -F" "` at least already using (the whole statement is a little longer). If I do use awk -F"XY=| " it doesn't work anymore. I always get an empty string. Even on `$1`. It should be `$3` with those two FS. Any idea on why that would happen?

Comment: Since you mention `-F" "` and `-F"XY=| "`, do you have space or `|` in your text.  Please complete data, and I will try to help you.